# Does sphinxtrain generate the MFC files?

Tags: sphinx4

I was wondering why the MFC files for the an4 database was up for downloading when in reality if you train your data in sphinxtrain, it says that it automatically generates the .MFC files.

I tried running both the an4 .RAW version and the .SPH version and configured my config file but still it won't create .MFC files. Do I have to create it on my own?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does on stage `000.comp_feat`. There is a log in `logdir/000.comp_feat` folder which might tell you what is wrong.

You need to use SPH database and you need to adjust the config accordingly with type `nist`, extension `sph`.

If features are not created it most likely means you did not install sphinxbase properly, for example, `sphinx_fe` is not in your `PATH` or you did not configure linker to load `libsphinxbase.so`. To check that run `sphinx_fe` from the command line.